# 'module' object is not callable in Python with package

Tags: python, class, module, runtime-error

I had create a Python package in my project with name **text_analysis,** and inside a class **TextAnalysis** with a method **search_records**

[image]

When I write a test in the main.py I can import TextAnalysis, but the ojbect (with IDE) doesn't show the method **search_records**. If I write the **test.search_records(barcode)** I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:..../main.py", line 19, in <module>
    analysys = TextAnalysis(bib)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

[image]

Comment: The line with the error is `test = TextAnalysis(bib)` not `test.search_records(barcode)`. `test.search_records` doesn't show because the previous line was invalid. Also consider actually writing your code to posting images.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why I can (1) import TextAnalysis, (2) create test object, but test object has not search_records method

Comment: By "test object" do you mean `test = TextAnalysis(bib)`? If so, no object was created. That line is invalid as `TextAnalysis` is a **module** and not a class nor a function.

Comment: By any chance is there a `TextAnalysis` class in the **TextAnalysis.py** file? Is that what you mean to import?

Comment: If I remove the package and I put all files (not elegant way) in the same folder, test.search_records is working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are defining a class in TextAnalysis.py that contains the modules you want to call. If you would rather call individual modules without a class structure within TextAnalysis.py, call them as TextAnalysis.module_name().

Here is a simple example: [Class vs Module structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEwcv.jpg)